# After setting up static ip in /etc/network/interfaces and my DNS in /etc/resolv.conf, I still can not get a connection

Tags: debian, networking, ip

On Debian, I tried following guide to set my static IP address: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEa1xopeufQ

These are what my **`/etc/resolv.conf`** and **`/etc/network/interfaces`** look like:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain hsd1.ut.comcast.net.
search hsd1.ut.comcast.net.
nameserver 1.1.1.1

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 10.1.10.57
netmask 255.0.0.0
network 10.1.10.0
broadcast 10.1.10.255
gateway 10.0.1.1
```

Of course, I removed all the default comments that are there when typing this.

I reset my computer after doing this and when I do `ifconfig` or `ip a` it shows that all the addresses have been changed correctly.

But, after all that work when I do `ping www.google.com` it says:

```
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is the output of some other commands:

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp3s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 enp3s0

$ ip route show
default via 10.0.1.1 dev enp3s0 onlink
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.10.57
```

When running `ip route show` and another device (my Thinkpad), here's what I get:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 60
10.0.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.50 metric 600
```

The only thing in common is the `10.0.1.1`.

What should I do?

Comment: Your gateway needs to be on the same subnet as your address.
Try using a netmask of 255.0.0.0

Comment: A more general solution - please check the IP address, Netmask, and Gateway values for your specific network. If you're using `netmask 255.255.255.0` your `address` and `gateway` must have the same first three octets (only the last of the four numbers can be different). If they really are `10.1.10.57` and `10.0.1.1` then you'll need `netmask 255.0.0.0`.

Comment: @roaima I set my netmask to 255.0.0.0 and I have the same error.

Comment: Are you sure `10.0.1.1` is the correct gateway?

Comment: A better test of functioning network connectivity is pinging the gateway and nameserver, because that does not involve DNS.

Comment: What is the problem with just running with the configuration your DHCP server (presumably on your router) asigns? Note that DHCP lends addresses, so it very well can be lending your desired fixed address to something else, the result won't be pretty. Yes, you can reserve addresses to to be lent in DHCP, or assign always the same to a given MAC. But most home WiFi routers hide those configuration options from you.

Comment: @pburrows, yes the output of `ip route show` is:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev enp3s0 onlink
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.10.57
```

The website I read told me it was the "10.0.1.1". Maybe it's wrong.

Comment: Yes most likely it's wrong, you can check what it is by checking another device on the network that works, sometimes it's `10.0.0.1` or even `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1`. Once you find the correct address of your router it should work.

Comment: @pburrows the output of `ip route show` on another device? here it is on my thinkpad:

default via 10.0.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.50 metric 600

The only thing in common is the `10.0.1.1`.

Comment: If that's the case then your router is probably configured with 255.255.255.0 (/24) too. Set your address to `10.0.1.60` and netmask to `255.255.255.0`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to double check the correct gateway and netmask then ensure you assign an IP that is part of the same subnet.

```
address 10.0.1.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.1.1
```